# Realloc a Pointer, where to say 'it's a pointer'?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc, realloc

I have one problem using realloc. I am unable to realloc an array of int.

Now that the realloc is fixed, my only problem is that I am not able to trigger the for. Here is it at the moment:

```
int insereAIndice(int* Tab, int index, int insertion, int taille) {
    Tab = realloc(Tab, taille * sizeof (*Tab));
    int i;
    for (i = taille-1; i <= index+1 ; i--) {
        printf("%d", Tab[i]);
        Tab[i] = Tab[i-1];
    }
    return *Tab;
}
```

Here is the "important" line:

```
*Tab = realloc(*Tab, taille * sizeof (*Tab));
```

And here is the rest of the code:

Main.c

```
#include "functions.h"
#include "functions.c"

/*       TP 3 - ESIEE-IT Rémy JARDIN        */

int main() {
    int saisie, index, insertion, taille;


    // Création du tableau avec des valeurs aléatoires.
    printf("Creation du Tableau. \nNombre de caractere du tableau : ");
    scanf("%d", &saisie);

    int *Tab = ArrayCreate(saisie);

    printf("Voici le tableau nouvellement creer : \n");
    Affichage(Tab, saisie);


    // Insertion d'une valeur 'insertion' à l'index 'index'. Avec décallage.
    taille = saisie;

    printf("\n ! Mode Insertion ! \nNouvel Endroit souhaiter a partir de 0 : ");
    scanf("%d", &index);

    printf("Nouvelle valeur souhaiter : ");
    scanf("%d", &insertion);

    insereAIndice(Tab, index, insertion, taille);
    Affichage(Tab, saisie);
 
    free(Tab);
    return 0;
}
```

functions.h

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *ArrayCreate(int saisie);
int randomizer(void);
int insereAIndice(int* Tab, int index, int insertion, int taille);
int Affichage(int* Tab, int max);

#endif
```

functions.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "functions.h"


int *ArrayCreate(int saisie) {
    int i;
    int *Tab = malloc( saisie * sizeof (*Tab));
    if (Tab==NULL) {
        printf("Not enough Memory");
        exit (1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < saisie; i++) {
        Tab[i] = randomizer();
    }
    return Tab;
}


int randomizer() {
    return 1 + rand() % 100;
}


int insereAIndice(int* Tab, int index, int insertion, int taille) {
    *Tab = realloc(*Tab, taille * sizeof (*Tab));
    int i;
    for (i = taille; i < index ; i--) {
        printf("\n - %d", Tab[i]);
    }
    return *Tab;
}


int Affichage(int* Tab, int max) {
    // Affichage
    int i;
    printf("\n Resultats : ");
    for (i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        printf("%d - ", Tab[i]);
    }
    return *Tab;
}
```

And this is what GCC gives me:

```
functions.c: In function 'insereAIndice':
functions.c:26:20: warning: passing argument 1 of 'realloc' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     *Tab = realloc(*Tab, taille * sizeof (*Tab));
                    ^
In file included from functions.h:5:0,
                 from main.c:1:
f:\logiciel\mingw\include\stdlib.h:486:40: note: expected 'void *' but argument is of type 'int'
 _CRTIMP __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW  void *realloc (void *, size_t);
                                        ^~~~~~~
In file included from main.c:2:0:
functions.c:26:10: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     *Tab = realloc(*Tab, taille * sizeof (*Tab));
          ^
```

Thank you !

Comment: `insereAIndice` is completely wrong.

Not only the inside of the function is wrong, bit how it is used is wrong too. Look at the `realloc` function itself. It receives a pointer argument, *and returns a pointer result*. You need to understand why this is *necessarily* the case, and then apply this understanding to `insereAIndice`.

Comment: When using pointers, we use and returns address, so this is not what we should use for dynamic array ?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. There is a very specific question. Why does `realloc` *need* to return an address? Could it have been defined as `void realloc(void* ptr, size_t size)` or `int realloc(void* ptr, size_t size)` or in some other similar way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to `realloc` is a pointer.  `Tab` is declared as an `int *`, so that means `*Tab` is an `int` which is why it doesn't match the type of the parameter.  This also means the return type doesn't match what you're assigning it to.

So pass the pointer instead of what it points to.

```
Tab = realloc(Tab, taille * sizeof (*Tab));
```

But on the following lines another problem becomes apparent:

```
for (i = taille; i < index ; i--) {
    printf("\n - %d", Tab[i]);
}
```

The array has been resized to have `taille` elements, so this loop reads past the end of allocated memory.  You presumably want this instead for the allocation:

```
Tab = realloc(Tab, index * sizeof (*Tab));
```

So then you're not longer reading past allocated memory (assuming the array was resized to be larger), but now you're reading uninitialized
values.

Comment: This fixes the compilation problem but does not fix the real problem.

Comment: Thanks ! I don't have the error anymore, but the program never go in the for. I don't have any printf of Tab[i]. Do you think it comes from the pointer ?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  Right, I tried it. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Well, it doesn't seems to work... In fact the loop is never triggered.